# External hyperlink in HTML file with Jekyll format

Tags: html, hyperlink, jekyll

I am using the [Minimal Mistakes](http://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/) Jekyll theme to create a website. I forked the repository and I am editing an HTML file, [`index.html`](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/master/index.html), to include an external hyperlink.

The following code results in text that is hyperlinked correctly.

```
My favorite website is <a href="https:\\www.google.com">Google</a>.
```

[image]

However, the hyperlinked text does not have the blue color formatting that the creator of this theme uses in his hyperlinks ([example](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/quick-start-guide/)) as shown here:

[image]

I have looked at other forks of this theme and they all seem to have replaced `index.html` with `index.md`. If i want to keep `index.html`, how can I achieve the same blue color formatting in my hyperlinks? I feel like I am, more generally, misunderstanding how Jekyll themes allow formatting to be used in individual HTML files.

**How does one use a Jekyll theme like Minimal Mistakes to allow theme-consistent HTML formatting of hyperlinks?**

Comment: CSS controls any jekyll themes styles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]This is all controlled in your themes style sheets. Not sure about 'minimal mistakes' but any jekyll theme is controlled with plain css.

My blog leverages jekyll and all my `<a>` tags are styled with (i am using SASS):

```
a {
  color: $blue;
  text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  &:hover, &:active {
    color: $blue;
  }
}
```